# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

Tags: android, apache, installation, android-8.0-oreo, abi

Adding the dependency to the build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

causes the error I mentioned in the title:

https://i.gyazo.com/865266f2561566be63d0fbee8e125eff.png

I started a new project in Android Studio and added that dependency just for being completely sure so you can reproduce the same steps, and its proved. (Notice I added the splits and packaging options mentioned in other posts and none of them worked).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/getLibs.ps1'
        exclude 'lib/getLibs.sh'
        exclude 'lib/gson-2.2.2.jar'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // HERE
    implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

}
```

Seems like this version of Apache is no longer working with Android versions from Oreo and up, but with all the previous ones.